# traefik proxy for docker container running in host network

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine, traefik

i am running traefik as a proxy in docker container
i am using DockerToolBox in windows 10
the traefik proxy was able to recognize the service app which is running in 127.0.0.1, but the service app is actually running in docker **host** = 192.168.99.x ip

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse_proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker 
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "8081:8080"

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - backend

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
  labels:
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.default"
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.port=80"
  network_mode: host

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

in the Traefik dashboard  http://192.168.99.100:8081
it shows http://127.0.0.1:80 for whoami service
instead of http://192.168.99.100:80
any help would be appreciated.
i want **network_mode: host** to pick **192.168.99.100** instead of **127.0.0.1**

Comment: you need to edit your `/etc/hosts` file in on your `host`

Comment: what should be there in /etc/hosts file ?

Comment: 192.168.99.100 localhost

Comment: yes , its already there

Comment: and in the container also ?

Comment: Did in container also, but still no success..

Comment: Is there anything that I should try from traefik point of view?

Comment: do i have to add hosts file entry in windows machine(C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) or inside docker-machine(/etc/hosts) ?

Comment: The answers above seems not working any more, updated at 2021.06.09

Answer (score 0):

As [traefik official documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/#host-networking) says, when resolving service IP, first it

> try a lookup of `host.docker.internal`

and second

> if the lookup was unsuccessful, fall back to `127.0.0.1`

This means we can just add a host in the traefik container, using `--add-host {docker0_IP}`(it's the bridge's IP, you can easily use `docker inspect {NAME_OF_TRAEFIK}` and find the IP of Gateway(for me, it's `172.18.0.1`). If you use docker-compose, you can use add following lines to your definition of traefik:

```
extra_hosts:
  - host.docker.internal:{docker0_IP}
```

Also, I find that it's ok to use the IP my eth0 IP, which means the IP of your LAN(for me, it's `192.168.0.20`).

Then, recreate traefik and everything works like a daisy.